# How to Fetch Month Part if Date is in mmYYY format(mm-->Month,YYYY--->Year)?

Tags: hive

I need to fetch 'month'  from one column in which date stores in mmYYYY(032019) format.I need to fetch the month column and if months value is  in 01,02,03(Jan,Feb,march) then ,i need to generate new column as 2018-19.if value is 072019 then need to generate new value as 2019-20. Im trying below code but not getting desired result. Can someone please guide me how should i implement this.

```
    CASE WHEN month(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dt), 'dd-MM-yyyy'))) IN (01,02,03) THEN 
    CONCAT(CONCAT(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dt), 'dd-MM-yyyy'))))-1,'-'),
    substr(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dt), 'dd-MM-yyyy')))),3,4)) 
    ELSE CONCAT(CONCAT(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dt), 'dd-MM-yyyy')))),'-'),
    SUBSTR(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dt), 'dd-MM-yyyy'))))+1,3,4)) end
```

because of my dt column is not in 'dd-mm-yyyy' format so its not giving correct value due to some scenario i don't want to use direct sub-string function  to fetch month part from dt. I want to fetch it using month function or any other function which can fetch month part and then accordingly generate output column based on month part.

```
    Sample Data.
    dt=012019
    output : 2018-19

    dt=022019
    output : 2018-19

    dt=032019
    output : 2018-19

    dt=042019
    output : 2019-20

    dt=052019
    output : 2019-20

    dt=062019
    output : 2019-20
```

Comment: Which database you are using?

Comment: hive @mkRabbani

Answer (score 0):

below code worked for me.

```
    CASE WHEN month(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dt,'MMyyyy')))) IN (01,02,03)   
    THEN concat(concat(year(to_date(substr(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dt, 'MMyyyy')),1,10)))-1,'-')
    ,substr(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dt, 'MMyyyy')))),3,4)) 
    ELSE concat(concat(year(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dt, 'MMyyyy')))),'-'),
    substr(year(to_date(substr(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dt, 'MMyyyy')),1,10)))+1,3,4)) END
```